# modify the MyApp-Info.plist

Tags: iphone, ios

In MyApp-Info.plist, there is an entry called "Icon files", it is type of an array and there is one element in it now. What I am doing to retrieve this info by following ;

> NSDictionary    *plistDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  infoDictionary];
>    NSArray         *array           = [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"Icon files"];
>    NSLog(@"array is %@",array);

However, the console shows me that there are no elements in my array...Have I done something wrong above. Please advice me on this.

Thanks

PS: there is an image about **Icon files**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper key for the "Icon files" item is `CFBundleIconFiles`. You can see the rest of the actual keys by selecting the plist in the file browser, right-clicking and selecting Open As > Source Code.

Comment: I have not tried it yet.Is it possible to add or remove item for CFBundleIconFiles by programming ?

Answer (score 1):

When you look at your plist in Xcode, right-click on the window and select "Show Raw Keys/Values" from the menu.  It will give you the actual dictionary key.

Or: `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]);`